# OpenLDAP schema not loaded

Tags: ldap, window, openldap

I am testing OpenLDAP for window

After installing OpenLDAP , I do not change any line of config file , and I run slap daemon, but it seem some schemes not loaded , see the output console :

```
...
config_back_db_open
config_build_entry: "cn=config"
config_build_entry: "cn=schema"
config_build_entry: "cn={0}core"
config_build_entry: "cn={1}cosine"
config_build_entry: "cn={2}nis"
config_build_entry: "cn={3}inetorgperson"
config_build_entry: "olcDatabase={-1}frontend"
config_build_entry: "olcDatabase={0}config"
config_build_entry: "olcDatabase={1}bdb"
...
```

and here the schemes expected to load (slapd.conf)

```
 include        ./schema/core.schema
 include        ./schema/cosine.schema
 include        ./schema/nis.schema
 include        ./schema/inetorgperson.schema
 include        ./schema/openldap.schema
 include        ./schema/dyngroup.schema
 include        ./schema/misc.schema
```

why shemes openldap , dyngroup ,and misc could not be loaded , i tested it by viewing schema explorer in jxplorer program ,i found there are no attributes and classes that defined in those schemes .

Is there any config i need to make those schemes load

i want create my own schema

Appreciate any suggest

Thank ^^

Answer (score 0):

I have the following which works. Try the order shown, same as in slapd.conf when distributed. I don't think you can load them all. If this order doesn't work you need to use slaptest -f slapd.conf to list any errors.

```
include         schema/core.schema
include         schema/cosine.schema
include         schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         schema/ppolicy.schema
#include        schema/connexitor.schema
#include        schema/corba.schema
include schema/dyngroup.schema
#include        schema/eduperson.schema
include         schema/java.schema
#include        schema/krb5-kdc.schema
include schema/misc.schema
include schema/nis.schema
#include        schema/openldap.schema
#include        schema/samba.schema
```